# Eclipse keep splitting my Test annotation

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse keeps splitting my Annotation, I would prefer the annotation to be on one line.

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = RerunOnFailure.class, groups = { "Android" })
public final void news() {
```

But using Eclipse formatter, I always get the below code snippet. Please let me know how to fix it thanks!

```
@Test(
        retryAnalyzer = RerunOnFailure.class, groups = { "Android" })
public final void news() {
```

Comment: Try adjusting the formatter settings.

Answer (score 1):

Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter then Edit
[image]